# Matlab Single-Layer perceptron

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to update the value of 'w' in a for loop but it always remains the same. In the first step, w must be zero.

```
d = 1;
a = 0.01;
w = [0 ; 0];

for i=1:250
    X = [1 ; myData{i,1}];
    Y = sign(w'*X);
    w = w + a*(d-Y)*X ;
end
```

'myData' is a matrix including values of X. Could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Can you give an example of data that causes this problem. I replaced `myData{i,1}` with `rand()` to test your code, and `w` definitely changed.

Comment: Sure. Samples of data: -0.2418 , -1.6919 , -0.3198 , -0.1002 , -3.1231 , -0.7153 , -1.7333 , -1.7734 , 0.0135 , 0.1163 , 0.2160

Comment: Could you please explain how can I replace myData{i,1} with rand()? Would rand() go through all the values in first column of myData matrix?

Comment: I was just using `rand()` to make up data to test with.

Comment: The value `w` isn't changing because `sign(w'*X)` is 1, so `(d-Y)` is always zero. If, for example, you had (large) positive numbers in `myData` then I think `w` would change.

Comment: I'm confused with sign function. Is it correct? : It returns 0 if the corresponding element of X equals zero. I read this sentence in this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html

Comment: sign(x)=1 of x>0, 0 if x==0, or -1 if x<0. Since you are dealing with floating point arithmetic, `sign(w'*X)` will effectively never be precisely zero, so in your code `sign(w'*X)` will virtually always be 1 or -1.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Let me change the initial value of w to see what happens.